# My css styles custom have no effect on laravel deployment

Tags: php, css, laravel, web, deployment

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/assets/css/creative.css')}}" type="text/css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{asset('/assets/css/custom.css')}}" type="text/css">
```

I have custom my css like that, I save it on my public/assets/css/custom.css and public/assets/css/creative.css, I access the style from resources/views/partial/header.blade.php

My local web changes according to custom css style.

BUT

I try to push my update css to server (deploy), but the style of web not changed. How to fix it? I've been stuck for a few days.

Comment: did you try with ctrl + f5 and clear the cache from browser? are you using any cdn , like cloudflare?

Comment: I have solved this one, I add ?v=2 after name css style like assets/css/custom.css?v=2 and It worked!

Comment: You can post the answer for your question, it can help others passing by the same problem.

Answer (score -1):

do

1. php artisan config: clear
2. php artisan cache: clear

or

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('/assets/css/custom.css') }}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" >
```